# jQuery identify clicked child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('click', ".t_box", function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

    alert(id);

 });
```

HTML Code:

```
        <div class="t_box" id="<%= t.id %>">
            <div class="tname">
                <div id="collapse">
                <%= form_tag('http://localhost:3000/ts/collapse_ts', :method => 'post', :remote => true ) do %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag(:t_id, t.id) %>
                    <%= image_submit_tag "collapse.png" %>
                <% end %>
                </div>
```

Whenever I click on the div #collapse on my page, my alert responds with the <%= t.id %>, meaning it is not seeing the actual element that i am clicking.  It should display 'collapse'.  I have tried setting the z-index:9999 for #collapse but I still can't get it noticed by jQuery.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [target attribute](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) of [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to get the actual element that triggered the event

```
$(document).on('click', ".t_box", function (e) {
    var id = e.target.id
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
      alert(e.target.id); // The id of the clicked element
  });
```